# where to store api access token in nodejs

Tags: node.js, security, local-storage, bearer-token

I have a react+nodejs setup for a web application. From the Nodejs(server-side) I connect to a third party server using the bearer token.

> Step 1: Call the third party login URL with username and password. I
>   will get a Token in the response with expiry details.
>
> Step 2: Send other requests with the valid token.
>
> Step 3: Before sending request I need to check if the token that I am
>   having is expired or not. If not expired, proceed step 2. Otherwise,
>   proceed with step 1 and then step 2.

I know, in the React application, I can store the token in local storage, and I also can check if it is expired or not.

How can I do this in NodeJs(server-side)? Do I have to store the token in the database along with expiry time? Or is there any other secure way to store the toke on server temporarily?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a properties file, also you could create environment variables (I think thist is a better option).